# Why isn't the score showing correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

I'm still a beginner in python, so I decided to make a rock, paper game.
For some reason, when the user or computer wins, it doesn't give them a point until the next round.

```
import random
games = int(input("")) #how many games
usersc = 0
compsc = 0
for x in range(games):
    score = (str(usersc) + "-" + str(compsc))
    user = input("") #ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
    comp = random.randint(0,2)
    if user == 'ROCK':
        if comp == 0:
            print("tie " + score)
        elif comp == 1:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + score)
        else:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + score)
    elif user == 'PAPER':
        if comp == 0:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + score)
        elif comp == 1:
            print("tie " + score)
        else:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + score)
    elif user == 'SCISSORS':
        if comp == 0:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + score)
        elif comp == 1:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + score)
        else:
            print("tie " + score)
    else:
        print("try again")

if compsc > usersc:
    print("loss")
elif usersc > compsc:
    print("win")
else:
    print("tie")
```

For example, when the computer wins, it says loss 0-0 when it should say loss 0-1, but then the next round it'll say 0-1.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the thing is counting towards the next round,

Comment: you are calculating score before increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you store score in a variable before incrementing it so you will always be 1 game behind. The simplest way to ensure the score is always correct would be to create a function to get the score like this...

```
def get_score():
    return str(usersc) + "-" + str(compsc)
```

This would ensure the latest user and comp score values are always used.
Using this the code becomes...

```
import random

games = int(input("")) #how many games
usersc = 0
compsc = 0

def get_score():
    return str(usersc) + "-" + str(compsc)

for x in range(games):
    user = input("") #ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
    comp = random.randint(0,2)
    if user == 'ROCK':
        if comp == 0:
            print("tie " + get_score())
        elif comp == 1:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + get_score())
        else:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + get_score())
    elif user == 'PAPER':
        if comp == 0:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + get_score())
        elif comp == 1:
            print("tie " + get_score())
        else:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + get_score())
    elif user == 'SCISSORS':
        if comp == 0:
            compsc += 1
            print("loss " + get_score())
        elif comp == 1:
            usersc += 1
            print("win " + get_score())
        else:
            print("tie " + get_score())
    else:
        print("try again")

if compsc > usersc:
    print("loss")
elif usersc > compsc:
    print("win")
else:
    print("tie")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are printing `loss+score` or `win+score`,

first update score as `score = (str(usersc) + "-" + str(compsc))` and then print it.